# Couldn't Serialize NSData Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I couldnt serialize the following JSON data. I can't see anything wrong in it.

```
[{"id":2182,"title":"HEAVEN ON EARTH","content":"Description","post_date":"2014-07-28 09:29:45","post_modified":"2014-07-28 09:29:45","abc_featured":"","abc_rating":"0","abc_recommended":"","abc_phone":"","abc_address":"","abc_address2":"","abc_postcode":"","abc_suburb":"","abc_state":"NSW","abc_website":"http:\/\/","abc_email":"Pralead@hotmail.com","abc_lat":"-1000","abc_lon":"10000","abc_closed_txt":"","yes_event":"","from_event_date":"","to_event_date":"","abc_location":"","abc_age":"","abc_cost":"","abc_prebook":"","abc_parentaccompany":"","abc_changingfaciltiy":"","abc_playarea":"","abc_pramaccessibility":"","abc_breastfeedingarea":"","abc_refreshments":"","abc_inoutdoor":"","abc_parking":"","abc_freetrail":"","feature_name":null,"feature_value":null,"feature_available":[],"image1":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07\/IMG_0014.png","image2":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07\/IMG_0011.png","image3":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07\/IMG_0009.png","Monday_from_time":"","Monday_to_time":"","Tuesday_from_time":"","Tuesday_to_time":"","Wednesday_from_time":"","Wednesday_to_time":"","Thursday_from_time":"","Thursday_to_time":"","Friday_from_time":"","Friday_to_time":"","Saturday_from_time":"","Saturday_to_time":"","Sunday_from_time":"","Sunday_to_time":""}]
```

CODE TO SERIALIZE IS:

```
NSArray *jsonArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
```

_downloadedData is the data I am geting from the JSON API.
I CAN SEE THE DATA COMING THROUGH THE NSLOG.

Comment: Try logging the `error` parameter if `jsonArray` is `nil`.

Comment: Is the JSON in the question from a dump of _downloadedData?

Comment: there is no problem with serialization problem only with data.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum the JSON in the question has problems, the main one is "null" for the value of a dictionary item.
Ex: "feature_name":null.

`NSDictionary` values must be an object.

Is the JSON in the question a `NSLog()` of `_downloadedData`?

Comment: nah! _downloadedData is the data that we have to serialize! I dont know what was the problem but the program seems to be working now, I didnt do anything. Thanx for ur time guys. How to close the topic? That JSON I got from the browser.